# How to write excel page header from worksheet formula?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Ran into a problem trying to change value of `Worksheets.PageSetup.CenterHeader`. Now this value can be written/read by passing value with `=` operator and the following would work nicely as supposed:

```
Sub Test()
    Call writeHeaderValue(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), "What what")
End Sub

Sub writeHeaderValue(ByRef mysheet As Worksheet, ByVal writeValue As String)
Set mysheet = ActiveSheet
    Debug.Print mysheet.Parent.Name
    Debug.Print mysheet.Name
    Debug.Print mysheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    mysheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = writeValue
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

But what causes me headache and can't figure out is that if I call this same writeHeaderValue from a function that I call from a formula in a worksheet, it does show the value and the reference to the worksheet seem to be correct but it fails to change the value. There are no errors from the compiler or any unexpected such, but the value just won't change. Odd thing about this is that the debug.print part clearly shows that I have correct reference and it also shows the current value of that property but it doesn't change so there must be something wrong in the following part:

```
Function writeValue(ByVal myValue As String)
Application.Volatile
Dim mysheet As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Set r = Application.Caller
Set mysheet = r.Parent

    Call writeHeaderValue(mysheet, myValue)
writeValue = myValue
End Function
```

To try this work, you can then use formula for ex.

```
=writeValue("TEST")
```

This should change document headers center value to read "TEST" but as you should find out it doesn't. **So my question is simple as this - what can be done to make the writeValue function work?**

I have gut feeling that it has something to do with using Application.Caller but this is something I want to work so that the reference to sheet is passed based on the cell that the formula is in. Second guess is that there is something happening during the calculation that disables the writing functionality during, but you tell me.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think that the problem is, that you call `.PageSetup.CenterHeader` from the UDF (User Defined Function) `writeValue()`. Excel is known to behave odd in UDFs sometimes. E.g. you are not able to change cells within UDFs: `mysheet.Range("A1").Value = "aa"` within `writeValue()` won't change A1 and won't throw an error in VBA too. So I assume it is just not possible to write the `.PageSetup.CenterHeader` within a UDF.

Comment: Thanks @Peh, I believe this might very unfortunately true. But if there is some workaround, I would definitely be happy.

Comment: Just don't do it in a UDF. Use the `Worksheet_Change` event or something to read the value of a specific cell on any changes within the worksheet and write that to the header or use a button event or something. I don't know what your goal is so these are just suggestions. UDFs are a bad approach for this specific task anyway: Imagine if there was more than one cell containing the `=writeValue()` function this would mess up.

Comment: Thanks @Peh , that is actually pretty good suggestion. I think I will do something like that.